# Does spring have @Stereotype annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, stereotype

I want to group some of my annotation to use them in more simple way. I read [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqc.html) about @Stereotype annotation.
I want to achive something like this:

```
@Stereotype
@AnnotationA
@AnnotationB
@Annotationc
@Target(...)
@Retention(...)
public @interface GroupAnnotation {
}

@GroupAnnotation
class X {}

@GroupAnnotation
class Y {}
```

But whenever I tried to use this annotation I got the following error message in IntelliJ:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Stereotype'
```

So is there any way to use this annotation in spring? Or do u have any alternatives of grouping annotations?

I'm using spring 2.7.1 and Java 11.

--- UPDATE ---

My real life scenario related to use @JsonFormat annotation. I wanted to setup it in one place and use it in many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Combining Spring's annotations

Annotation `@Stereotype` is a part of Java EE (Jakarta EE) world, and it's not available in Spring. More over, it's not needed in Spring.

Assuming that you need to combine several annotations provided by Spring, here's how it can be done:

```
@SpringAnnotationA // something like @RestController, @RequestMapping("/foo"), etc.
@SpringAnnotationB
@SpringAnnotationC
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // mandatory
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) // limit the types of elements on which annotation can be applied
@Documented               // to reflect the annotation in the documentation
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

A more concrete example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@Validated
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
public @interface MyController {}
```

By the way, here's the right place to go when you need Spring documentation:

- [spring.io - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/)

## Combining Jackson's annotations

In order to create a custom multi-annotation from several Jacksons annotations, you need to apply a special meta-annotation [`@JacksonAnnotationsInside`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.html) provided by Jackson:

> Meta-annotation (annotations used on other annotations) used for indicating that instead of using target annotation (annotation annotated with this annotation), Jackson should use meta-annotations it has. This can be useful in creating "combo-annotations" by having a container annotation, which needs to be annotated with this annotation as well as all annotations it 'contains'.

*Example:*

```
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyJsonAnnotation {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this solution but it is not working on my side. I don't see the grouped annotations on my target just the group annotation. :(

Comment: @HowToTellAChild I can't tell you anything without knowing exactly have you tried, and what means not working. The concrete example combining `@RestController`, `@RequestMapping` and `@Validated` **should work** correctly. Which annotations exactly you're trying to combine and what's happening? Are you applying **only Spring's** annotations? For instance, if you would want to add `AllArgsConstructor` from Lombok, your attempt would fail.

Comment: I tried to use `@JsonFormat` annotation this way. So `@AnnotationA` would be `@JsonFormat` in my real life scenario and `@GroupAnnotation` meant to be some company level configuration.
For instance:
`@JsonFormat(...)
@Target(...)
@Retention(...)
public @interface CompanyConfig{
}`
When I tried to read this information from code I can't do that. Also there is a binding to this annotation and the related services didn't catch this marker.

Comment: @HowToTellAChild `@JsonFormat` is **not** coming from Spring - it's a Jackson's annotation (have a look the import statement). `@Target` and `@Retention` are **meta-annotations** that you need to specify the details of your custom annotation. What are your annotations `@AnnotationB` and `@AnnotationC`?

Comment: @HowToTellAChild Please update the Question and show all the annotations you're trying to combine (i.e. replace `@AnnotationA`, `@AnnotationB` and `@AnnotationC` with your real ones). If these are all Jackson's annotations, then you need to add `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` + meta-annotations.

Comment: The thing is `@AnnotationB` and `@AnnotationC` were for example purpose, I used `@JsonFormat` only. So my real life scenario related to use `@JsonFormat`. I didn't know the relevance of different "type" annotations like spring or jackson. But anyway when I used `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` it helped me out! So if you could mention this in you answer I will accept it as a proper solution.